# MSBuild AfterPublish Target

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, msbuild-task

I want a particular file copied in with the published output of my web project. I tried changing the `Build Action` to `Content` and changing the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. This works fine except that it buries it down in a sub folder the same way it is in the project.

I do not want it buried down in a sub folder. I want it sitting right next to the rest of of the published output. I thought I might instead handle this problem using the `AfterPublish` Target.

Can someone show how I might do this? I think I'd need to know the path that the person selected in the Publish dialog somehow.

Comment: Might have a solution.  You want the file in same **containing** folder that contains the published output or you want the file in the root folder of published output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Publish feature is unfortunately buried *deep* inside of Visual Studio itself. Because of this you are **very limited** in what you can do to extend the process. Because of this even a simple task as you have outlined here is not really possible, at least from your project file. If you need to get better control of your Web Deployments I would suggest that you take a look at [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) and/or [MSDeploy](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/).
What I would do it add a Web Deployment Project which will prepare your Web App for deployment, including this custom file copy, and then allow MSDeploy to perform the actual deployment for you.